# Bootstrap link buttons with json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, twitter-bootstrap

Currently my code works as this. Links though fine.

```
    var button =
        "<button class='redirect-button' data-url='LINK'>Compare</button>";
    $("#tableid").append("<tr  ><td>" + section +
        "</td><td>" + no + "</td><td>" + price +
        "</td><td>" + button + "</td></tr>");
    $("#tableid").find(".redirect-button").click(function() {
        location.href = $(this).attr("data-url");
    });
}
```

Although when i try and use the bootstrap button the button shows in the table but does no longer follows through to the link.

```
 var button =
                "<button class='btn btn-info' data-url='LINK'>Compare</button>";
            $("#tableid").append("<tr  ><td>" + section +
                "</td><td>" + no + "</td><td>" + price +
                "</td><td>" + button + "</td></tr>");
            $("#tableid").find(".btn btn-info").click(function() {
                location.href = $(this).attr("data-url");
            });
        }
```

How  do i go about making it linkable again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your selector (".btn btn-info") is wrong in find method. It is must be ".btn.btn-info".

see;

```
$("#tableid").find(".btn.btn-info")
```

Answer (score 2):

When you use `.find(".btn btn-info")`, you have a mistake on the selector `.btn btn-info`. 
Your bootstrap button is something like that :

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info">My Button</button>
```

You can access to the button like that :

```
 $("#tableid").find(".btn.btn-info").on('click', function(){
                        ^--- has class .btn and .btn-info
   location.href = $(this).attr("data-url");
});
```

Read this article http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#class-html